# Creating an array from values in a Wordpress loop

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have tried to work this out and looked for a solution but no luck.

My wordpress loop looks like this...

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'=> 'reviews',
    'meta_key' => 'post_id',
    'meta_value' => $pageid,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' =>20,
    'orderby' => rand
);
query_posts( $args );
if (have_posts()) :while (have_posts()) : the_post();
```

Each post has a custom field called 'rating' which contains a number between 1 and 5.

What I want to do is create an array form the value of 'rating' for all posts in the loop... to look something like this...

```
$ratings=array("5","4","2","5","3","5");
```

So that I can then calculate the median value.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: So your primary issue is to find this median value? (i.e. array won't be used anywhere else)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, in your loop:

```
$meta_rating = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'rating', true);
if($meta_rating!=='') {
   $ratings[] = $meta_rating;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I am still confused... I want to take the custom field 'rating' on each post and the find median rating for that field for all the posts in the loop. I am not starting with any array... I need to create an array or find another way of working out the median value. Apologies if either of the above answers already address this, I just don't understand how to correctly use them.

Comment: Sorry, think I have it now from above answer. Thanks.